# Busted control panel after migration

Tags: craft3, control-panel, hosting

Recently migrated a site from staging server (Digital Ocean VPS) to client's production server – pretty basic shared hosting (their choice). They were running PHP 5.3 so got them to upgrade to PHP 7.3. I also ran the [Craft Server Check](https://github.com/craftcms/server-check) first and everything passed fine. No composer so had to FTP everything and set permissions etc...

Front end is live but Typogrify and Map plugins aren't working for reasons so far unknown. The bigger problem though is the control panel cannot load styles or scripts (403 errors on cpresources dir) and cannot login. I upped permissions on that directory to 774 and still no luck. Hosting support hasn't responded so I'm kinda stuck. Never encountered these dramas before. Any advice very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so this is a really weird one. On a hunch the host decided to change all permissions to their default 755, and now everything works! I'm left scratching my head but there it is. Not quite sure how those permissions impact Craft security but at least it's not 777, which I was worried they'd need.